# Does SearchView with "app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"" have bug?

Tags: android

1. After the `MenuItem` has expanded with `SearchView`, the overflow menu shows another search item. My expected behaviour of it is that it won't show another search item while the `SearchView` is expanded.
2. After the `MenuItem` collapsed, the search item is no longer there. My expected behaviour of it is that it will collapse back into an icon.

First state:
[first state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y6yQh.png)
Second state:
[second state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c1qTS.png)
Third state:
[third state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cxGz6.png)
Fourth state:
[fourth state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NTX4y.png)

My current solution is to change from `app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"` to `app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"` and everything works fine.

layout\main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"
        app:title="Main" />
</LinearLayout>
```

menu\main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item android:id="@+id/search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_white"
        android:title="Search"
        app:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView" />

    <item android:id="@+id/enter_delete_mode"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_delete_white"
        android:title="Enter delete mode"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

MainActivity.java:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.MenuItem.OnActionExpandListener;
import android.widget.SearchView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnActionExpandListener {
    private SearchView searchView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Toolbar t = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(t);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater mi = getMenuInflater();
        mi.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

        MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.search);
        searchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();
        searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
        searchView.setQueryHint("Search...");
        searchItem.setOnActionExpandListener(this);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.enter_delete_mode)
            Toast.makeText(this, "Pressed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem item) {
        searchView.setIconified(false);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem item) {
        searchView.setIconified(true);
        searchView.clearFocus();
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like a bug to me, though i can't find any article talking about that.

Nevertheless i found a workaround and i hope this helps somebody.

To prevent the `searchView` item from being listed under the overflow menu while expanded, change its `ShowAsAction` attribute to `SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS | SHOW_AS_ACTION_COLLAPSE_ACTION_VIEW` during runtime when the `searchView state` is expanded.

```
@Override
public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem item) {
  //Force searchItem not to be listed under overflow menu.
    item.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS |
                         MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_COLLAPSE_ACTION_VIEW);
    return true;
}
```

To prevent the `searchView` item from disappearing when collapsed simply call `invalidateOptionsMenu` for the menu to be redrawn.

```
@Override
public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem item) { 
    //Call menu to be redrawn
    invalidateOptionsMenu();
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Ya, same here, I can't find any sources that talk about it either. Not even in the site to file bug reports for android.  

Yup, they can use this solution if they really want to use the `ifRoom` flag.